# R convert character to a vector

Tags: r

I have a `character`:

```
 x <- 'c(1, 2, 3)'
```

I'm trying to convert it to a `vector` in one line using the `eval` function:

```
 print(class(eval(x)))
```

but the result is still a `character`:

```
 [1] "character"
```

Comment: `eval(parse(text = x))`